# How can I get a more specific 400 validation error instead of a 500 error when using params.require?

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, error-handling, parameters, form-submit

I'm working through a full-stack project using Rails on the back end and React on the front end. I have a Sign Up form designed to accept a new user's information and avatar and pass it to the Users controller on the back end. For whatever reason though, if the form is empty or incomplete, it throws a 500 Internal Server Error instead of a more informative 400 error.

User Controller is :

``
class UsersController < ApplicationController
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, with: :render_unprocessable_entity_response

def index
users = User.all
render json: users
end

def create
user = User.create(user_params)
session[:user_id] = user.id
render json: user, status: :created
end

```
  

    private
    
      def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :birthday, :username, :password, :password_confirmation, :avatar) 
      end
    
      def render_unprocessable_entity_response(invalid)
        render json: { errors: invalid.record.errors.full_messages }, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    
    end
```

Sign Up Form in React (specifically, my Submit function)

```
  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData();

    data.append("[user][first_name]", firstName);
    data.append("[user][last_name]", lastName);
    data.append("[user][email]", email);
    data.append("[user][username]", username);
    data.append("[user][password]", password);
    data.append("[user][password_confirmation]", passwordConfirmation);
    data.append("[user][avatar]", avatar);

    fetch("/signup", {
      method: "POST",
      body: data
    })
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        response.json().then((user) => onLogin(user));
      } else {
        response.json().then((errorData) => contextData.setErrors(errorData.errors));
      }
    })
  };
```

Response I'm getting in the console when I submit an empty form:

```
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"first_name"=>"", "last_name"=>"", "email"=>"", "username"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "avatar"=>""}}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 97ms (ActiveRecord: 49.6ms | Allocations: 9234)
```

When I remove the "params.require(:user)" portion, it gives me the validation errors I was expecting, but then I'm unable to create a new user due to have ActiveStorage works and requires data.

Comment: Using a multipart form request from React is a really clunky way to integrate it with ActiveStorage. ActiveStorage has a built in Direct Upload feature that lets you upload the attachments before the record is created with JavaScript. Don't reinvent the wheel. https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#direct-uploads

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot wrong in the premise of this question so please bear with me.

First lets look at the docs for `ActionController::Parameters#require`:

> Ensures that a parameter is present. If it's present, returns the
> parameter at the given key, otherwise raises an
> ActionController::ParameterMissing error.

Rails will rescue this error on the framework level but you can rescue it on a per controller level with `rescue_from 'ActionController::ParameterMissing'`. But remember that the purpose of `require` isn't validation. Its just to bail early if the request is missing the correct structure and should not be processed anyways - because classical Rails applications nest their parameters in a key with the same name as the resource by default.

In an API application you don't even have to follow that pattern - you could just as well use "flat parameters" or standards like JSONAPI.org.

Then there is the use of:

```erb
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, with: :render_unprocessable_entity_response
```

This pops up from time to time as a "clever" way to DRY out API's. In your case it won't even work because `User.create` does not raise - `User.create!` does.

It's also not a good use of exceptions. Exceptions should be used for exceptional events that should cause an immediate halt of the execution. A user passing invalid input is not exceptional in any way - in fact its completely mundane.

If you want to DRY your API in a good way instead do it the way that [the Responders gem](https://github.com/heartcombo/responders) does:

```ruby
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    user = User.create(user_params)
    session[:user_id] = user.id 
    respond_with(user)
  end
end
```

```
class ApplicationController
  # ...
  private

  def respond_with(resource)
    if resource.valid?
      resource.new_record? ? render_created_response(resource) : render_updated_response(resource)
    else
      render_unprocessable_entity_response(resource)
    end
  end

  def render_created_response(resource)
    render json: resource, status: :created
  end

  def render_updated_response(resource)
    render json: resource, status: :ok
  end
end
```

This creates an explicit flow of methods that can be overridden in subclasses. Instead of an implicit flow created by what is actually a callback.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  private

  def render_updated_response
    # do something wild and craazy
  end
end
```

Reserve the use of `create!` for contexts where creating the record should not be expected to fail (like in a seed file or non-interactive contexts) or to cause rollbacks inside of a transaction.